# A question about sets of limit points of continuous functions.

Tags: functions

> Let $f:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$ be a continuous function and $A\subset\Bbb{R}$ be defined by $A=\{y\in\Bbb{R}:y=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)$, for some sequence $x_n\to+\infty\}$. Then $A$ is necessarily
>
> A. A connected set
>
> B. A compact set
>
> C. A singleton set
>
> D. None of the above

I constructed a continuous function in which $A$ would include only natural numbers (or any infinite, discrete, non-connected and non-compact set that you'd like). In other words, I thought we could pick and choose any infinite sequences $\{x_n\}$ that we liked, and create the corresponding set $A$. Hence, I answered D.

However, my friends say that A has to include **all** possible limit points $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} f(x_n)$ for any infinite sequence $\{x_n\}$. This set is connected.

Which is the right answer?

Comment: @Matt- No. We can choose different sequences for different limits.

Comment: This is not so. Let $f(x)=\sin x$. Then $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n\pi)=0$, $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(\pi/2+2n\pi)=1$ and $A=[-1,1]$.

Comment: My mistake. This is possible if the function does not converge ,right?

Answer (score 3):

The set $A$ is connected. Suppose that $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)=a$, $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(y_n)=b$ and $a<b$. Since $f$ is continuous, given any $c\in(a,b)$, by the intermediate value theorem you will be able to construct a sequence $z_n\to\infty$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(z_n)=c$.